# How do you show a list of tables in another database?

Tags: sql-server, system

I can use:

```
select * from sys.tables
```

in mssql to show a list of all tables in the current database. Is there anyways I can use similar syntax to show list of tables in another database?

Say I am using A with:

```
use A
```

statement, can I show tables in database B?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This does it for me (MS SQL 2005 and newer):

```
select * from your_database_name.sys.tables
```

Keep in mind that you (or whatever authentication context you're using) will still need read permission on that database.

To use your example:

```
use a;
go

select * from sys.tables; -- selects table info from a
select * from b.sys.tables; -- selects table info from b
```

Comment: The question and answer should be clarified as being applicable to MS-SQL 2005 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use:

```
select * from your_database_name.information_schema.tables
```